# How quickly do new spot instances come online when the number of instances fall below the target fleet capacity?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

From the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-fleet.html),

> The Spot Fleet also attempts to maintain its target capacity fleet *(sic)* if your Spot Instances are interrupted.

I have a spot fleet with just one instance but a variety of instance types chosen as the instance pool. When I receive a interruption notice (because of insufficient compute capacity, not because of market price), how long does it take for AWS to try and spin up instances of different types? Does it do so immediately or wait until the instance has been forcefully interrupted two minutes later?

Comment: I can't answer the question, but I will comment that if you need high availability it can be better to use two small instances and load balancer rather than one larger instance. That doesn't suit all applications, and load balancers while not expensive can cost more per month than small instance types, particularly spot instances.

Comment: Since health checks terminate and then launch, I assume interruptions would be treated the same way:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-fleet-requests.html#spot-fleet-health-checks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will wait until the instance has been fully terminated to start launching the new ones, this includes the spin-down time when your application will not be available. So from the 2-minute notice to having a new instance up and configured, it will take at least 4-10 minutes.